# Issue in analyzing json data on hive

Tags: apache-pig

I wanna analyse json data in pig ..here is my valid json data:

```
[{"author":"gjkfhvk","title":"gdfjhsdgfjk","published":1997, "reviews":[{"name":"fvdjk","stars":5},{"name":"dhjk","stars":4}]}, {"author":"ggkjhk","title":"gdfghfjhgh","published":1998,"reviews":[{"name":"jhj‌​k","stars":6},{"name":"fghh","stars":6}]}]
```

here is my pig command:

```
data = load '/home/user/Desktop/tej/pig.json' using JsonLoader('author:chararray,title:chararray,year:int,reviews:{review:(name:char‌​array,stars:int)}');
```

when I use this command to display the contents in data : dump data...

I getting output as :

```
Input(s):
Successfully read 3 records from: "/home/user/Desktop/pig.json"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 3 records in: "file:/tmp/temp1826337556/tmp244945211"

(,)
(,)
(gdfghfjhgh,{(jhjk),(fghh)})
```

not able to fetch the 1st array data that is  title and reviews data ..

Could you please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json is invalid.I've corrected it.See below

[image: Input]

```
{"author":"gjkfhvk","title":"gdfjhsdgfjk","published":1997,"reviews":[{"name":"fvdjk","stars":5},{"name":"dhjk","stars":4}]} {"author":"ggkjhk","title":"gdfghfjhgh","published":1998,"reviews":[{"name":"jhj??k","stars":6},{"name":"fghh","stars":6}]}
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: I changed the json but now getting output as:(gjkfhvk,gdfjhsdgfjk,1997,{(fvdjk,5),(dhjk,4)})
(,,,)

Comment: I have a question on sql query

Comment: find the no. of followers for a particular userID.

Comment: [User_ID]    [Follower_ID]
12                 13
12                 14
12                 15
16                 17

Comment: [User_ID]    
12                
12                 
12                 
16                  

[Follower_ID]
13
14
15
17

Comment: hi, i have a question on dml mapping to pig transformation can i ask.